# How can I save a substring of a line from a text file into an array of strings?

Tags: c, arrays, string, string.h

I have code that reads a `.txt` file:

```
Pancho: Juanka,Cony
```

The idea is to find the character `':'` and save it apart in an array of strings. The same with `Juanka` and `Cony` but instead, it's going to be when it finds `','` and `'\0'`.

Comment: Look into `strtok`.

Comment: Use `sscanf`... or `strchr` for _find the character_

Comment: Another alternative is `strcspn`. Personally, that's my favourite for this kind of task, as you haven't specified how spaces should be treated, which renders all three of the above potentially invalid, or at least technically difficult.

Comment: and save Pancho apart...*

Comment: `char sub[3][16]; sscanf("Pancho: Juanka,Cony", "%15[^:]: %15[^,],%15[^\n]", sub[0], sub[1], sub[2]);`

Answer (score 0):

While `strtok` will solve this problem, I believe it won't be a very maintainable solution. I intend to point out some problems with using `strtok`, and solutions to those problems.

---

**Problem #1**: Due to hidden state, `strtok` is *non-reentrant* and *non-threadsafe*; if you try to tokenise two strings simultaneously (e.g. interweaving sequences of function calls, or using multiple threads), you'll run into issues.

**Solution #1:** `strchr` and `strcspn` can be used instead to address this issue. I've demonstrated the ability to read lines in other answers<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14851925/c-how-to-read-string-lines-from-stdin-or-file-memory-save/14854115#14854115),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30271631/dynamically-allocate-user-inputted-string/30272281#30272281)</sup> using `strcspn`; these could be easily adapted to use `strchr` instead, or to use characters other than `'\n'`.

---

**Problem #2:** `strtok`, `strchr` and `strcspn` all operate upon a string which needs an intermediate array to exist within. You're reading from a file; if you don't *need* that intermediate array because you can read the fields directly into their corresponding arrays, then eliminating them might expose more advanced optimisations and cleaner, more maintainable code.

**Solution #2:** The following code [demonstrates](http://ideone.com/rkbw7i) performing the *splitting* directly from the file by using `fscanf`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define WIDTH_STR(width) #width
#define FIXED_FIELD(width) "%" WIDTH_STR(width)
#define TERMINAL(set) "[^" set "]%*1[" set "] "

#define W 1024
int parse(FILE *f) {
    char x[W+1], y[W+1], z[W+1];
    if (fscanf(f, FIXED_FIELD(W) TERMINAL(":"),  x) <= 0) { return EOF; }
    if (fscanf(f, FIXED_FIELD(W) TERMINAL(","),  y) <= 0) { return EOF; }
    if (fscanf(f, FIXED_FIELD(W) TERMINAL("\n"), z) <= 0) { return EOF; }
    printf("<%s>\n", x);
    printf("<%s>\n", y);
    printf("<%s>\n", z);
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("parse returned: %d\n", parse(stdin));
}
```

---

**Problem #3:** All of the above solutions reach peak optimality (in terms of maintainability/complexity and computational efficiency) when you assume fields are *fixed width*. Once that assumption becomes invalid, it makes *much more sense* to use `fgetc` to read and parse one byte at a time, reallocating as necessary to accomodate for the *variadic fields*.

**Solution #3:** I've demonstrated the ability to read words of variable length in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30271631/dynamically-allocate-user-inputted-string/30272281#30272281), which would be easily adapted to read and parse single tokens into separate dynamic allocations. This is likely suffer the drawback of expensive reallocation necessary to allow your users to enter *enormous* (multiple-megabyte) field values which wouldn't typically be supported as fixed width arrays with automatic storage duration.